# What is the expanded form of this generator for loop?

Tags: python, numpy, loops

I'm trying to figure out the expanded form of this inline for loop.

```py
from numpy import array

out_seq = array([in_seq1[i]+in_seq2[i] for i in range(len(in_seq1))])
```

What would be the equivalent expression in the form

```py
from numpy import array

for i in range(len(in_seq1)):
    ...
```

I'm assuming I'd need to initialize `out_seq = []`, append to it while iterating, and convert to the numpy `array` type last (like `out_seq = array(out_seq)`)? I've tried a few different solutions but nothing's worked yet.

Comment: "inline for loop" is called a "comprehension" or "generator".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, but you shouldn't put `[]` around `out_seq`, because it's already a list.

```
out_list = []
for i in range(len(in_seq1)):
    out_list.append(in_seq1[i]+in_seq2[i])
out_seq = array(out_list)
```

You can also use `zip()` to avoid the explicit indexing of the two input sequences:

```
for x, y in zip(in_seq1, in_seq2):
    out_list.append(x+y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the best way to do this would be to expand it like so:

```py
from numpy import array

out_seq = []
for i in range(len(in_sequences[0])):
    summ = in_seq1[i]+in_seq2[i]
    out_seq.append(summ)
out_seq = array(out_seq)
```